# Making something travel in a circle in Javascript using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

This is my first time using canvasses, and my first time using Javascript to make a full on game-type thing, so forgive the beginner confusion!

I am trying to make a sort of circular Flappy Bird type thing where you travel around a circle, are drawn into the circle in a sort of gravity like way, and clicking makes you rise up. Go too high and you die, go too low and you die. However, I am falling down at the first hurdles...

The two main problems I have right now, starting with the smallest, is with the .clearRect function. I currently have it vaguely clearing behind the ball as it moves, but this is a little imperfect and cuts into the middle circle if it gets too close. If I set the whole window to clear on each frame, everything flashes horribly; is there a better way of doing this?

The second problem is just making the ball go in a circle... I have tried a lot of solutions, and I know that this is very likely to be a huge failing of my maths skills, but I can't make it orbit the main circle at all. I can make it move, and I have made it bounce off of the walls so that I can at least see what it's doing, but it just isn't circling. I imagine I'll be asking about the other aspects of this game at some point in the future if I have the same difficulty, but, as I said, I'm trying to learn!

In the dx and dy variable, 'sun' represents the middle point of the circle that I am trying to get the planet to orbit around. The rest of the variable is based on one answer I found elsewhere but I haven't managed to get it to work either.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      sun = 300,
      sunRadius = sun / 2,    
      x = sun +110,
      y = sun -110,
        
      angle = 0,
      distance = 10,
      dx = sun + sunRadius * Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180),
      dy = sun + sunRadius * Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180),  
    
      planetRadius = 10;
    
    
    
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = canvas.height = sun * 2;
    
    function makeSun() {
      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
      context.arc(sun, sun, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = "yellow";
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();
    }
    
    function makePlanet() {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, planetRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.fillStyle = "green";
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = "green";
      context.stroke();
    }
    
    function draw() {
      context.clearRect(x + -20, y - 15, 40, 40);
      makePlanet();
      
       
       if (x + dx > canvas.width - planetRadius || x + dx < planetRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
      }
      if (y + dy > canvas.height - planetRadius || y + dy < planetRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
      }
      
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    }
    
    
    setInterval(makeSun, 10);
    setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so

#### first :

the screen is flashing because you are setting two different intervals for makesun and draw. javascript makes zero promises that it won't update the screen between the time it cals makesun and draw. the best solution I think is to effectively clear the whole rect then redraw your sun ( the graphics are simple enough so you won't have performance issues).

### second :

to animate the ball, you want to get the current time and decide how fast (in rotations / sec) you want it to go. As others suggested, requestAnimationFrame is better than setInterval, as it passes you a timestamp.

### example

I've adapted your code to make the planet spin. I also added movement to the sun so you see the planet is actually relative to it. Have a look and please ask if there's something you don't understand.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      checkbox = document.getElementById("moveSunBx"),
      sun = 300,
      sunRadius = sun / 2,
      controllables = {
        movesun : false,
        rotationspeed : 1/2 // half a turn every second (timestamps are in milliseconds)
      },

      distancePtoS = 110,//distance from planet to sun
      planetRadius = 10;

var   planetAngle = 0.0,// Starting angles
      sunAngle = 0.0,
      lastTimestamp;


var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(controllables, 'movesun').name("move sun");
gui.add(controllables, 'rotationspeed', -6, 6).name("planet speed");// in turns per second

function makeSun(x, y) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
  context.arc(x, y, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "yellow";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}

function makePlanet(x, y) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, planetRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = "green";
  context.stroke();
}
    
function draw(timestamp) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);//immediately ask for next frame
  
  if(!lastTimestamp){
    lastTimestamp = timestamp;
    return;
  }
  

  var speed = Math.PI * 2.0 * controllables.rotationspeed / 1000, // convert speed from turns per second to radian per millisec 
      timestep = timestamp - lastTimestamp;
      
  lastTimestamp = timestamp;//we save the stamp

  planetAngle += timestep * speed;//we update the angle depending on the currentspeed and the timestep

  //angle = angle % Math.PI / 2;// this is for better comprehension, Math.cos and sin do the clamping for us
debugger;
  //let's make the sun move!!!
  if(controllables.movesun){
    sunAngle += timestep * speed;
  }
  var sunx = sunRadius + Math.cos(sunAngle /2) * distancePtoS;// <- sin of 2 angle gives a beautiful infinity
  var suny = sunRadius + Math.sin(sunAngle) * distancePtoS / 2;


  //x and y don't need to be kept, I made them local to draw()
  var planetx = sunx + Math.cos(planetAngle) * distancePtoS;
  var planety = suny + Math.sin(planetAngle) * distancePtoS;

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  makeSun(sunx, suny);
  makePlanet(planetx, planety);
}
    
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = canvas.height = sun * 2;
    
draw();//we start the cycle
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is pretty much the perfect answer, and I am beyond appreciative of your guidance! This has helped further my understanding of both how to approach this kind of thing, and about how these parts of Javascript work in general, so huge thanks to you.    My one question would be about using timestamps: would these be the ideal way to handle all animations like this in canvasses, or are they just ideal here because of the type of animation I'm using?

Comment: I'd say timestamps are pretty much the way to go, at least for any game-like endeavour. Normally you would calculate a difference with the previous timestamp, which gives you "how much time passed since the last `draw()` call". Then you give that to your animation engine so it can calculate the animation without "choppiness". Here the circular movement is simple enough that I can derive it from total time. I found that the book "Game Programming Patterns" helped a lot to understand these concepts. here for the "game loop" pattern : http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

Comment: Ah very good information to have, and the book link looks very interesting. I will read through it over time and pick up as much as possible; thanks again!

Comment: No idea if you're still able to respond to this, but I do have one further question that I've been grappling with. Basing the rotation speed off of the timestamp seems to cause the planet to skip around if I try to change it part way through, by adding a click event that adds even a small amount to it for example. What is the best practice for changing things that are hooked to the timestamp, increasing or decreasing speed in this case, in general?

Comment: Then you'd need to disconnect from absolute timestamps, keep the current angle from frame to frame, and calculate a timestep. I can't access a computer until monday, but if you still need it by then, i'll update my answer!

Comment: Ahh interesting! I won't have access to a computer until Sunday, but I will give it a good go and see if I can work it all out. I want to make as many moving parts into changeable variables as possible to make the game/(attempt to) emulate gravity as best as possible, so so it's good to know that disconnecting from absolute timestamps is necessary for that. Thank you yet again, I appreciate your insight!

Comment: Interesting! I'll update the example to reflect timesteps instead of timestamps! If you want to simulate movements more closely, you'll want to look into the equations of motion. It is too hairy a subject for a SO answer, but it has been covered thoroughly, Gafferongames has a good intro article on this : https://gafferongames.com/post/integration_basics/

Comment: so, @BatBut, how is it going? timesteps coming along smoothly?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to reply to this ages ago but got caught up in playing with the code! It's coming along well, I've been toying with getting gravity simulation to work when I've had time lately (to varying degrees of success) but I wouldn't have even been able to do that without your help; thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use requestAnimationFrame() instead of the set intervals and you shouldn't have the flashing afterwards and the equation for a semicircle is y = ±√(r^2-x^2)
Use a variable to determine if it should be positive or negative and change the x variable of the orbiting object each draw to move it in a circle

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm reading up on requestAnimationFrame as an approach to this kind of thing in general, and the equation is incredibly helpful!